# When a list item is clicked in the modal change the text and add class active to another list item

Tags: jquery

I have a menu with some categories:

```
<div class="col p-0 m-0">
    <ul class="Categories__Menu">
        @foreach($categories->take(6) as $category)
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#" name="category" id="{{$category->id}}" href="#">{{$category->name}}</a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
        <li><a  data-toggle="modal" id="showCategories" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" href="">More</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If the user clicks in More it opens a modal with more categories, the modal have this content:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="categoriesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <ul class="modal-list row">
                            <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                <a class="">All categories</a>
                            </li>
                            @foreach($categories as $category)
                                <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                    <img src="{{ $category->image }}"/>
                                    <a name="category" id="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have some jquery to do an ajax request to get the conferences that belong to the clicked category. This is working fine.

But I want that the clicked category becomes the active in the menu "Categories__Menu". This is working, the clicked category stays active.

But there is a issue. When a category is clicked in the modal the text "More" changes to the text of the clicked category, this is correct, but this item that changed the text from "More" to the text of the clicked item should also change the class to active.

Do you know how to achieve that?

Fiddle with the issue: jsfiddle.net/69LnLa7y/7

jQuery:

```
    $("a[name='category']").on('click', function(){
         if($(this).closest(".modal-list").length) {
    $('#showCategories').html($(this).text()+' <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    $('#categoriesModal').modal('hide');

  }
  // $('#categoriesModal').modal('hide');
  $(".active").removeClass("active")
  $('#showCategories').addClass('active');


  var category_id = $(this).attr("id");

  //$('.Categories__Menu li').addClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');


        $.ajax({

            url: '{{ route('category.conferences',null) }}/' + category_id,
            type: 'GET',
            success:function(result){
                $('#conferences').empty();
                var newConferences='';
                var placeholder = "{{route('conferences.show', ['id' => '1', 'slug' => 'demo-slug'])}}";
                $.each(result, function(index, conference) {
                    var url = placeholder.replace(1, conference.id).replace('demo-slug', conference.slug);

                    newConferences += '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">\n' +
    '                        <div class="card box-shaddow">\n' +
    '                            <img class="card-img-top" src='+ conference.image +' alt="Card image cap">\n' +
    '                            <div class="card-body">\n' +
    '                                <h5 class="card-title">'+conference.name+'</h5>\n' +
    '                            </div>\n' +
    '                    </div></div>';
                });
                $('#conferences').html(newConferneces);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error.status)
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/69LnLa7y/7), there are some points that you should consider:

- You should remove `active` class from all of your relevant `li` tags at the first of your function (According to what you specified in your question)
- inside your `if`, you should add `active` class to your `li` which has `a` tag with id of `showCategories`( you added `active` class to `showCategories` which is wrong because it is a `a` tag and not a `li` tag.
- you should add `else` condition to your `if` so that if the selected item is not from your modal, you should add `active` class to the `li` parent of the selected `a` tag.

[Here is the working Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0puh90h/)